# Why do my assets load incorrect CSS styles?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

In "app/assets/stylesheet/application.css.scss" I have following code:

```
 /*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Then I have "styles.css.scss", where I have all the code of my app.

There is a problem with precompiled assets on my localhost, where the application loads the CSS rules from two files, from "styles.css.scss" and "application.css.scss".

When I check an element that has incorrect CSS rules, I see that the CSS rules are loaded from "styles.css.scss" and "application.css.scss". But, "application.css.scss" is empty, so how is possible that this file has the CSS rules?

I've tried also deleting the directory "public/assets", but it didn't help.

How do I fix this? I've been working on it for several hours with no progress.

Comment: How are you loading these into your `appliction.html.erb`?

Comment: This way: `= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"`

Comment: I am assuming this is happening to you in `development` mode?

Comment: Yes, it's happening on localhost.

Comment: Although I doubt this is the answer, when you use require_tree you aren't guaranteed the order in which the files are processed.

Answer (score 0):

In development mode by default you have the following in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

> "In development mode, assets are served as separate files in the order they are specified in the manifest file." (Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

If you set `config.assets.debug` to `false` then all the styles(in this case) will be combined and placed into `application.css`.  But with `config.assets.debug` as `true`, your `application.css` will be empty unless you have some `css` rules specified there.

I hope I have not misunderstood your question :)